# Zonal Statistics in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, geotiff-tiff, zonal-statistics

I moved from QGIS 2 to QGIS 3 I cannot seem to be able to use the zonal statistics package.

Basically what I want to do is take the world pop GeoTIFF for a country and then calculate the population based on a shapefile/polygon. I was able to do that easily in QGIS 2 but the package seems to be missing in QGIS 3. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Zonal statistics for raster layers can be found in the processing toolbox:

https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html?highlight=zonal%20statistics#raster-layer-zonal-statistics

Answer (score 1):

Open the `'Processing Toolbox'` via `Processing > Toolbox` and search for *"Zonal Statistics"*

[image: example]

Additionally to the option suggest by @babel, there are two more options, respectively

- [SAGA Zonal raster statistics](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.0/statistics_grid_5.html) a.k.a. Zonal Grid Statistics
- [GRASS r.stats.zonal](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.stats.zonal.html)