QGIS equivalent to ArcMap Zonal Statistics as Table
In ArcGIS Pro there is a "zone field" part that let us specify the category when using the "Zonal Statistics as Table", but in QGIS 3.20.3 I don't see that.
Does anyone know how can we choose a specific attribute?
For example I would like to use Land Cover Data and use the field "Code_18"?
I saw some suggestions to other similar questions such as using the Zonal Histogram Tool. But in those tools, we cannot specify the field.
What worked for me before was using the Zonal Statistics Tool in conjunction with "Group Stats". However it is too complicated, I would like to know if there is an easier way to do that, hopefully with one tool?

Use SAGA for Raster Zonal Stats in QGIS https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/371250/zonal-statistics-in-qgis-3

What do you mean exactly with "Group Stats"?

Are you asking about vector or raster zone data (land cover)?

The QGIS Processing framework is based on a modular approach and provides specialized tools that can be combined together to obtain the desired result.
You need to:

use the "Vector geometry - Dissolve" processing algorithm in order to "dissolve" the features based on the values in a specific layer's field
use either the "Raster analysis - Zonal histogram" or the "Raster analysis - Zonal statistics" processing algorithm having the dissolved layer as input.

You can create your own custom procedure using the Model designer and combine the two processing algorithm together:

